# Updating Redux state partially using object.assing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I got a React/Redux app that receives posts from a server. So far, I got the RECEIVE_POSTS right in my reducer, which looks as follows:

```
function posts(
    state = {
        items: []
    },
    action
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                items: action.posts,
            })
        case ADD_POST:
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Now for the other cases, I am struggling with the `Object.assign` syntax. How would I update the state in the ADD_POST case , where a newly created post contained in `action.post` is to be appended to the existing items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `CREATE_POST` refers to `ADD_POST` based on receiving post data, it would look like this :

```
case CREATE_POST:
  return {...state, items: state.items.concat(action.post)};
```

No need to use object assign since you can just `concat` your post with the already existing posts from your state. As a reminder, `concat` does not mutate state, it returns a new array with the added `post`.

Answer (score 1):

This is done assuming that a single post inside an array is being passed

```
function posts(
    state = {
        items: []
    },
    action
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                items: action.posts,
            })
        case CREATE_POST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                items: [...state.items, ...action.post]
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't that overwrite the previous posts? The newly created post needs to be appended to the existing items.